# How to migrate passwords to a different hashing method

Tags: security, hash, migration

When changing the password-hashing algorithm for an application, how should the system migrate the values already saved in the database? I am well aware of the fact that I can't migrate them in their hashed form but that I need to have the input data in order to calculate the new hash.

There are two situations in which I have access to the input data:

1. During login
2. When the user changes her password in her profile settings

obviously only during one of these I am able to save the new hash to the database to migrate the password.

Although all of my colleagues are voting for method one my gut tells me to not do that. Is there a recommended way?

Comment: #1 works for me. All you have to do is check both hashes, and if the old one matches what's in the DB, just replace it with the new one. This allows a smooth transition.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I see no reason not to do this on logon.  Is there a reason you don't want to do #1?  You validate against the new hash, if that fails, validation against the old hash algorithm.  If that works, I'd then write the new hash over the old one.  This means that your passwords will be converted faster, since users probably logon more than they go to change their password.  Unless you force people to, I doubt most will change it on their own.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an **alternative solution** if you don't won't to touch the old authentication code (ie. switching to a new framework) or just want to rid yourself of the old password fields:

1. Backup the existing table of passwords and then delete all the existing entries in the passwords column in this table (and update the column type if necessary of course) so that it is ready to receive fresh passwords with the new encryption.
2. The next time users try to log in, check the passwords table and if the user exists with no password, then prompt them with "*We have implemented a system wide upgrade and all accounts will need to be re-verified from email. We have sent you an email, please use the email to complete your account upgrade. We apologize for the inconvenience.*"
3. The users will go to their email and click a link that may say something like "Re-confirm my account". They will be taken to a page that requires some secure token parameter, received from the link given in the email. This page will now ask them to enter their username and password (more importantly password) to complete the upgrade. You can require they enter the password twice, to guard from typos. Technically, you are creating their password here. Just simply ask for it in 2 inputs labeled "password" and "confirm password".

There are of course both **pro's** and **con's** to this solution as well, in comparison to the others. The good thing is you don't have to add old hashing code in your new environment and have it sit there until the one day all your users have finally logged in again. But this solution comes with the price of writing extra code as well (code to send emails/token and so on). You'll have to compare that work to the work involved with your proposed solution of intercepting the form input coming in, checking against old hashing, and then passing onto new authentication code. Just another idea for you.

Comment: "The good thing is you don't have to add old hashing code in your new environment and have it sit there until the one day all your users have finally logged in again."  You don't need to do that either; you can yank it even if not everyone has converted yet and force them to a forgot password workflow.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this IT scenario: Company A Took over Company B with similar business model, All the customers need to be merged into one bigger system owned by Company A, while decommissioning user system in company B which has different password hashing algorithm, 
The best Implementation to getting this done is to **Force password Change** for all migrated users via their registered email address.

Comment: Unless of course the users don't have access to their old email addresses anymore, in which case some alternative workflow is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get specific advice without knowing specifics about the problem.  I'm going to assume that the reason you want to change your password storage strategy is because your new strategy is going to be significantly more secure than your existing strategy.

If that's the case, then what's the possible advantage to waiting?  The idea is to mitigate the existing risk.  Users, realistically, very rarely change their passwords.  If you want to migrate to a new storage strategy, you should probably do it at login or you're just going to have a big database full of passwords with dubious security.