# Why didn't this rails migration preserve the value in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So our Rails 4.2 app had a custom password authentication mechanism (very similar to has_secure_password) before we switched to has_secure_password with the following migration:

```
def change
  rename_column :users, :encrypted_password, :password_digest
end
```

When I ran the migration, somehow the values of encrypted_password were not saved in password_digest.  Why might this be?  And what can be done to resolve it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure but unless you where using an identical encryption scheme, the users will not be able authenticate with their old `encrypted_password` as the result of hashing the cleartext will not match the previous system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864239/how-to-migrate-passwords-to-a-different-hashing-method

Comment: define "were not saved". `password_digest` has null values now?

Comment: the `rename_column` migration should not change/save anything but just rename the column! what was your expectation, what happened. please be more specific.